# QVideoWidget não exibe nada

Tags: c++, qt, reprodutor-de-video

Estou tentando utilizar as classes [`QMediaPlayer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html) e [`QVideoWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideowidget.html#QVideoWidget) para exibir um vídeo em um sistema que estou produzindo. Só que esses raios de classes não funcionam como esperado. O `QVideoWidget` simplesmente não aparece, não exibe o vídeo, não faz nada!

### O MCVE

Pra exemplificar o problema, eu construi um [*Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) com base [*no próprio exemplo da documentação do Qt 5*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideowidget.html#details). Abaixo se encontram os arquivos de configuração do [CMake](https://cmake.org/) (para configuração do ambiente - isto é, criação do projeto do Visual Studio ou do Makefile) e de código:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project (Teste)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build." FORCE)
  set_property(CACHE CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE PROPERTY STRINGS "Debug" "Release"
    "MinSizeRel" "RelWithDebInfo")
endif()

# Configuração do Qt
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5MultimediaWidgets REQUIRED)

# Cria o executável
if(WIN32)
    add_executable(Teste WIN32 main.cpp)
else()
    add_executable(Teste main.cpp)
endif()

# Adiciona as bibliotecas necessárias
target_link_libraries(Teste Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Multimedia Qt5::MultimediaWidgets)
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMediaPlaylist>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMediaPlayer *player;
    QMediaPlaylist *playlist;
    QVideoWidget *videoWidget;

    // Código tirado do exemplo em: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideowidget.html#details
    // -------------------------
    player = new QMediaPlayer;

    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4"));
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"));

    videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

    videoWidget->show();
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
    player->play();
    // -------------------------

    return app.exec();
}
```

### O Problema

Quando eu executo o código, o componente (`QVideoWidget`) aparentemente não "é criado" (apesar de ser exibido, já que pra garantir que o problema não é outro eu chamo `show` diretamente no desgraçado), pois a janela aparece "encurtada" (sem um tamanho padrão qualquer):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas mesmo se eu uso o mouse pra redimensionar a janela, não há nada sendo exibido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código não gera nenhuma exceção ou erro. No exemplo mínimo eu uso URLs de vídeos apenas para facilitar os testes (e tal qual está na documentação), mas no meu sistema local eu leio arquivos locais e o problema é exatamente o mesmo.

### O Ambiente

O meu ambiente de desenvolvimento é:

- Windows 10 64 bits
- CMake 3.5.0-rc3
- Qt 5.6.0 32 bits
- Visual Studio 2015

### EDIT

Acabei de testar no Ubuntu (16.04 64 bits) com Qt 5.7 (64 bits) e o problema é exatamente o mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Achei um pouco estranho o seu teste com urls externas, talvez seja necessário fazer download primeiro, pois o player não passa os dados pro codificador se o download não terminar, talvez ele reconheça frações do arquivo, mas ainda sim talvez seja necessário criar um handler temporário. Me diga, tentou com arquivos locais?

Comment: Ah, até suas perguntas vem aqui pra "humilhar" a gente que não sabe postar nada direito :D Pena que não posso ajudar ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No meu código eu uso arquivos locais, e também não funciona. Só usei URLs externas porque facilita a construção do [mcve]. De todas as formas, deveria funcionar igualmente (e tá como o exemplo da documentação). :)

Comment: @bigown Opa, desculpa ai. rs :)

Comment: Só me tira uma duvida, instou os codecs necessários? Se rodar em modo DEBUG aparecem erros de tentativas de usar os codecs.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu acredito que sim. Até porque a minha máquina roda os vídeos (os locais que eu tento executar são .mp4) no VLC sem problemas por exemplo. Além disso, eu já rodei em DEBUG e não apareceu erro algum. Mas, agora me tira uma dúvida: o exemplo mínimo que eu fiz roda normalmente aí pra você?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testei seu exemplo e ele realmente nem tenta rodar o arquivo, ao olhar o exemplo que enviou do site ele mostra assim:

```
playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
```

Me parece que há alguns erros na documentação, o `QMediaPlaylist` não tem o parâmetro pra receber `QMediaPlayer`, mas sim um `QObject`, ou seja isso deve ser apenas pra definir o `parent`, não tem relação com criar o player, parece um erro do tutorial deles, veja como está a classe `QMediaPlaylist`:

```
QMediaPlaylist(QObject *parent = 0);
virtual ~QMediaPlaylist();
```

Outra coisa que notei que ao adicionar os "media itens" você usou `QUrl`, mas acredito que o correto seja `QMediaContent`, tanto para arquivos remotos quanto locais.

Outra coisa que notei que é necessário definir o tamanho minimo do `QVideoWidget`, pois senão ele vai renderizar como `0`, também é possível adicionar ele dentro de um `QWidget` ou `QMainWindow` customizado.

O @LuizViera também me atentou a um detalhe, o `QUrl` não adiciona o `file:///` em arquivos locais, então é necessário usar `QUrl::fromLocalFile`.

O código para funcionamento básico seria assim:

```
QMediaContent videoItem1(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/Guilherme/exemplo.mp4"));
playlist->addMedia(videoItem1);
```

Acredito que o caminho correto seja este:

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;

playlist = new QMediaPlaylist();

//Define o playlist no player
player->setPlaylist(playlist);

//item index 0
playlist->addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl::fromLocalFile("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")));

//item index 1
playlist->addMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl::fromLocalFile("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4")));

videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

videoWidget->show();

//Define o minimo do tamanho do video
videoWidget->setMinimumSize(100, 100);

playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
player->play();
```

> **Apenas uma nota:** se aparecer uma mensagem semelhante a esta no log do Qt (em Windows):
>
> ```
> DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 80040266
> ```
>
> É devido a falta de CODECs para versão do tipo x86/32bit (conforme a tua versão)

Uma coisa que pode adicionar são os eventos para verificar outros erros (troque `[SUA CLASSE]` pela classe aonde irá organizar o principal, talvez a janela customizada de um player):

- Seu arquivo `.h` geralmente:

  ```
  public slots:
      void statusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status);
      void displayErrorMessage();
  ```
- Seu arquivo `.cpp` geralmente:

  ```
  void [SUA CLASSE]::statusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
  {
      switch (status) {
      case QMediaPlayer::UnknownMediaStatus:
      case QMediaPlayer::NoMedia:
      case QMediaPlayer::LoadedMedia:
      case QMediaPlayer::BufferingMedia:
      case QMediaPlayer::BufferedMedia:
          qDebug() << status;
          break;
      case QMediaPlayer::LoadingMedia:
          qDebug() << "Loading...";
          break;
      case QMediaPlayer::StalledMedia:
          qDebug() << "Media Stalled";
          break;
      case QMediaPlayer::EndOfMedia:
          qDebug() << "Media end";
          break;
      case QMediaPlayer::InvalidMedia:
          displayErrorMessage();
          break;
      }
  }

  void [SUA CLASSE]::displayErrorMessage()
  {
      qDebug() << player->errorString();
  }
  ```
- E adicione os sinais aos `SLOTS`:

  ```
  connect(player, SIGNAL(error(QMediaPlayer::Error)), this, SLOT(displayErrorMessage()));
  connect(player, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)), this, SLOT(statusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));
  ```

Também existe na documentação um exemplo completo para se estudar:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html

Um teste realizado:

[image: video gato]

link do video: http://9gag.com/gag/adj442N/cat-exe-stops-working

Comment: @LuizVieira acabei de notar duas coisas, a primeira é que devido ao QVideoWidget não ter largura a altura fixas a tela fica em branco, é preciso definir, ou então adicionar o seu QVideoWidget para uma janela existente, em ambos casos o video funcionou :)

Comment: Exato. Funcionou. Recapitulando, os problemas são então: 1) o `QVideoWidget` não tem um tamanho padrão e precisa ser ajustado manualmente (eu até notei que se vc deixa a cargo do usuário fazer o ajuste com o mouse, o som funciona mas o vídeo não renderiza corretamente); 2) para abrir arquivos locais é necessário usar `QUrl::fromLocalFile`, pois a url **precisa** ter o "file:///" no início; 3) continua...

Comment: 3) A documentação contém erros importantes: é necessário construir um `QMediaContent` e o carregamento de um arquivo remoto (de uma URL "http://...") não é tratada automaticamente pelo `QVideoWidget`. Eu já vou aceitar a sua resposta, mas se puder fazer um resumão mais sucinto será útil para outras pessoas no futuro (porque eu acho que deveríamos remover todos esses comentários). Outra coisa: adicione na sua resposta [o link para o exemplo mais completo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html), que funciona e é bem mais útil.

Comment: Ah, remove a parte que fala que o problema é devido à falta de Codecs (porque não é). E obrigado novamente pela ajuda! :)

Comment: @LuizVieira eu estava criando um exemplo que redimensiona o QVideoWidget, assim que conseguir terminar eu irei adicionar na resposta :)

Comment: @LuizVieira deixei a parte dos codecs para ajudar outros usuários, lembro-me que muitas perguntas que vi no SOen falam do problema, acho que é um adicional útil a comunidade :)

Comment: @LuizVieira editei a resposta para adicionar os detalhes que citou, só uma nota o QVideoWidget acho que não trata, quem faz o tratamento é o QMediaPlayer, tanto que você pode controlar o Network da classe dele.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme. :)